# Create reports but shouldn't be able to edit other reports in shared folder

Tags: reporting

We have created a shared reports folder "Project Shared Reports" and provided some pre-defined reports to the users in this folder. Users have 'View' access to this folder.

Now the requirement is that some users should be able to create new reports but they should not be able to edit other reports in the shared "Project Shared Reports" folder.

We did the following
We gave "Create and Customize" reports permission to the permission set and assigned to a user. But then user is able to edit other's reports in the shared "Project Shared Reports" folder as well.

I read some blogs and found this.https://www.wgcgllc.com/salesforce-report-permissions-pt-1/
As per this, if users have "Create and Customize" reports permission, then will NOT have the permission to edit other's reports in the shared folder but this is not what we are experiencing.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.
The issue was that users was having 'Edit' Access on the shared folder. After updating the access to View access, the functionality is working as desired